# Questions On Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus

Tags: calculus

Fundamental Theorem of calculus says that if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is continuous and differentiable on $[a, b]$ and also $F'(x)=f(x)$ 
Now I want to know that as $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then why $F'(x)=f(x)$ is not continuous on $[a, b]$

Comment: I don’t get the doubt at all : you start with a continuous function $f$, and then you are asking about why $f$ is continuous at the end?

Comment: That means $F'(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$

Comment: But then $F’ = f$ is a part of the theorem : so if $f$ is continuous, so is $F’$ because it equals $f$. So $F’$ Is continuous also.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that $F'(x)$ was not continuous? We could probably better help you through your confusion if you can explain what prompted this question. If it is because you've heard that derivatives are not necessarily continuous, that is true, but then those derivatives also don't satisfy the requirements of this theorem, so it doesn't apply here.